# Helper Test Error in Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, ruby-on-rails-4, helper

I am trying to write a test for a helper. Currently my codes look like this:

application_helper_test.rb

```
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../test_helper'

class ApplicationHelper < ActiveSupport::TestCase

  def test_title
    assert_equal "Test", title
  end
end
```

application_helper.rb

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def title
    controller_name.humanize
  end
end
```

But I get this error in my terminal, any help?

```
Run options: --seed 4320

# Running:

E

Finished in 0.022048s, 45.3556 runs/s, 0.0000 assertions/s.

  1) Error:
ApplicationHelper#test_title:
NameError: undefined local variable or method `title' for #<ApplicationHelper:0x007fd4eef00760>
    application_helper_test.rb:7:in `test_title'

1 runs, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess your assertion is the problem here. It should be:

```
assert_equal "Test", ApplicationHelper.title
```

Also, one advice is that rename your test class name from ApplicationHelper to ApplicationHelperTest.

**Update**:
Your module should be changed slightly:

```
module ApplicaitonHelper
   def self.title
      controller_name.humanize
   end
end
```

Comment: 'NoMethodError: undefined method `title' for ApplicationHelper:Module' doesn't fix it

Comment: @siaw23: Updated my answer. Try it as I do not have ruby installed in this machine. The answer is purely from my experience.

Comment: i get this: http://pastebin.com/43qNuU4P i see the problem is with the name of the method in the test. but why? i don't get it.